# What happens if federal statistical agencies and executive departments don't upload data regularly?

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, research, research-papers

If federal statistical agencies in USA and executive departments of the US Gov don't upload unbiased data on open data platforms or in general don't release information on time, are they penalized? Is there any law which governs them? Are they terminated, what happens exactly?